# How check if pages still not full loading after 12 second, using javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, redirect, pagespeed, device

I want this code `top.location.href= 'http://myweb.com/super-minimal-page.html';` only target devices that take a long time to load my page (maybe more than 12 second still not full loading my page).

Comment: What's the end goal?

Comment: @TejasManohar,i try to redirect visitor devices that take a long time to load my page (maybe because slow internet connection or low device perforomance). Redirect to my minimal web version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) will return `"complete"` when the page has finished loading. You can set a timeout and check if the value of `readyState` isn't `"complete"` after 12 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // Not complete. Document hasn't finished loading.
    if (document.readyState !== 'complete') {
        top.location.href = 'http://myweb.com/super-minimal-page.html';
    }
}, 12000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `Boolean` variable is loaded with false value on the top of your script
then create `setTimeout` function for 12 secound that refare to function you need to fire in case of the page is not loaded

in the document.load function set the Boolean variable to true and check for the variable in your pageNotLoaded function as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var pageIsLoaded = false;
  setTimeout(PageNotLoaded, 12000);

$(function(){

  pageIsLoaded = true;

});

function PageNotLoaded()
{
 if(!pageIsLoaded)
   {
     // do your code here
   }
}
</script>
```